# Is there any tips to get projects for junior graphic designer like me

Tags: communication

I'm starting to design from 2012 and I have made some design for some event (I'm the committee of the event) and sometimes I created it in my spare time. But, why can I get some money from it so I don't have to get money from my parents anymore (I am a college student now). Is there any tips for me to get some client so I can get paid from it? Big thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes? He asks for tips? It's a legit question.

Answer (score 2):

Would you hire someone with your exact skills for a job? If no, then it means you have to improve your abilities. If yes, then you may get a job soon.

If you are good enough try finding jobs via freelancing sites, forums, facebook groups, even Craiglists.

Be persistent and provide good quality and in a year your parent will start asking money from you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by:

- Talking to people close to you. Tell them what you want to help others with and ask if they know anyone who needs that. For example: creating a logo, designing a slide presentation, etc. Something that is aligned with your skills.
- There are online freelancing websites where there are lots of jobs you can bid on. They usually don't pay that much but they can be a gateway to get experience. You can try Upwork, Fiverr, Freelance.com .
- You can improve your portfolio by helping good causes, like a nonprofit or a community you feel drawn to. Talk to them and offer to help in exchange for a testimonial if they like your work. Then you can put those on your website and start your reputation.

Best of luck!